# Visual Studio UWP project creating error

Tags: visual-studio, win-universal-app

I downloaded Windows 10 SDK, I try to create a project UWP Blank, but this error appears: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZPiI.jpg). How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met the same issue like you.

To solve it please launch Visual Studio installer once again (before doing it remember to close VS). Select "Modify" option then select Features -> "Windows and Web Development" -> "Universal Windows App Development Tools" > Click "Update / Install".

Once you do it you should be able to create the project.

Comment: Oh, thank you, i accidentally forgot one point. They are called almost equally ("Tools and Windows 10 SDK" and "Windows 10 sdk")

Comment: Thats true and you should install both;)

Comment: I alredy understood :)

Comment: Oh, today i installed SDK (chose both point), restarted PC, but this error is continue.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I will go through it today and try to get back with another solution.

Comment: Sometimes this is really weird - Platform has still some bugs... ;)